# Flushing in pipelined architectures

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, mips

How is the flushing really implemented? I have an idea that on conditional branches, the prior instructions are flushed. But how are they actually flushed?

Answer (score 1):

They are not actually removed from the pipeline.
They are shifted out as the new instructions are shifted in, but there is logic which takes care that they are not "executed". 
Thus the system stays in the state it was when the 'flush' started.